# Как в Delphi определить в любом месте кода csDesigning находится ли сейчас в режиме разработки?

Tags: delphi

Как получить это значение для компонента понятно. А как получить это значение для произвольного места (для TObject or reference или local)?

Нужна функция, которая вернет true если Designtime сейчас, без создания нового компонента или какого-то общего локального компонента для этого определения. Может быть есть какой $define?

```
function IsDesignTime: Boolean;
```

Это rtti не подходит

```
function IsDesignTime: Boolean;
begin
  Result := TRttiContext.Create.FindType('ToolsAPI.IBorlandIDEServices') <> nil;
end;
```

это ниче такой

```
function IsDesignTime: Boolean;
implementation
var
  DesignTime: Boolean;
function IsDesignTime: Boolean;
begin
  Result := DesignTime;
end;
initialization
  DesignTime := ParamStr(0).EndsWith('\bds.exe', True);
end.
```

Есть еще варианты?

Написал либ но забыл всем TPersistent  указазать  события для IDE
owner а нет то зато с этим способом кучу объектов не нужно будет исправлять
в противном случаи при удаление объекта item IDE выдает ошибку

```
procedure TObjectLister.DoCheckObjectItem(Prm:PObjectListerEventPrm);
begin
    inherited ;//inherited DoCheckObjectItem
    if IsDesingTime and (GetObject(Prm.index) is TPersistent) then
    case Prm.Enum of
          sevAdd:               NotifyDesigner(Self,  GetObject(Prm.index) as TPersistent, opInsert);
          sevAddObject:      NotifyDesigner(Self,  GetObject(Prm.index)as TPersistent, opInsert);
          sevInsertObject:   NotifyDesigner(Self,  GetObject(Prm.index)as TPersistent, opInsert);
          sevInsert:            NotifyDesigner(Self,  GetObject(Prm.index)as TPersistent, opInsert);
          sevDeleteBefore:   NotifyDesigner(Self, GetObject(Prm.index)as TPersistent, opRemove);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: А можно какой-нибудь кейс использования? Этот флаг, навскидку, может понадобиться при разработке компонента (собственно, там действительно понятно что делать) или при разработке плагина / эксперта для IDE. Но плагин вне IDE бесполезен, поэтому определение там не нужно...

Comment: В принципе, вариант именно как вариант неплохой. Однако Делфи - это про компоненты, которые имеют свойство `ComponentState`. Не могу даже представить необходимость уточнения `IsDesignTime`  вне `IDE`. Скорее всего, у Вас типичная ошибка в проектировании. Либо Вы энтузиаст поиска новых подходов к решению задачи))

Comment: @Josef Švejk Написал либ но забыл всем TPersistent указазать события для IDE
owner а нет то зато с этим способом кучу объектов не нужно будет исправлять в противном случаи при удаление объекта item IDE выдает ошибку